# Преобразование строк в числа

Tags: java

Почему метод `Integer.parseInt(s)` суммирует только первое число?( вместо всех вводимых чисел?)

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10");
int count = in .nextInt();
System.out.print("Введите" + " " + count + " " + "чисел, через пробел");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scan.next();
String[] numbers = str.split(" ");
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
  for (String s: numbers) {
    res += Integer.parseInt(s);
  }
}
System.out.println("Сумма чисел= " + res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, зачем вам два цикла.
Вместо next() используйте nextLine()

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10");
    int count=in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите"+" "+count+" "+"чисел, через пробел");
    in.nextLine();
    String str = in.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = str.split(" ");
    int res = 0;
    for (String s : numbers) {
        res += Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    System.out.println("Сумма чисел= " + res);
}
```

Вообще, это ведь не python, чтобы придумывать обходные пути для ввода чисел через пробел. Можно ввести числа через пробел и Scanner будет считывать их друг за другом в цикле.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 10");
    int count = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите"+" "+count+" "+"чисел, через пробел");
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        res += in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Сумма чисел= " + res);
}
```

Comment: Действительно с nextLine работает! вот СПАСИБО!
Но в задачи зачем-то необходимо сперва
ввести кол-во элементов одним числом , затем
 считать числа с одной строки, для этого и был использован 2й цикл